# Is Mysql.pdb file useful?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I've search on google and stackoverflow and dba.stackoverflow and couldn't find any content related to this question. The basic question is Mysql.pdb useful somehow?

Reason to remove: The file is big[160mb]. I'm about to deploy a desktop application that download and installs mysql on the local machine. I store the zip in my web filestorage[traditional host and amazon s3] so I can rely on myself and prevent from Oracle removing it, etc.

The mysql version is: https://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/MySQL-5.7/mysql-5.7.17-win32.zip

The installer basically:

1. Download and Unzips the file
2. Execute the command "mysqld --initialize --init-file={app}\create_db.sql"
3. Configure the mysql server aas a Window Service
4. {Continue installation process}

Can I remove it without having unwanted behavior? Is there any other "useless" file on mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .pdb files are detailed information for use in debugging or reporting errors in the executables in MySQL. If you decide you don't need this functionality, you can delete the files

Comment: What will happen after deletion? Will a new (smaller) file be created?

Comment: Is there a way to clear the debug database without deleting it?